# I want to submit the form when last option of dropdown is selected options are generated dynamically

Tags: javascript

For example I am adding field after selecting the Parent then insert child field , I want to submit a form when select list is ended or select is on last child how to submit after I added all fields and if I have no child of select then submit

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var children = $H(<?php echo json_encode($tree['children']) ?>);

function showCat(obj, level) {
    var catId = obj.value;
    level += 1

    if ($('cat_container_' + level)) {
        $('cat_container_' + level).remove();


    }
    if (children.get(catId)) {
        var options = children.get(catId);
        var html = '<select id="cat_' + catId + '" onchange="showCat(this, ' + level + ')">';
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            html += '<option value="' + options[i].entity_id + '">' + options[i].name + '</option>';
        }
        html += '</select>';
        html = '<div id="cat_container_' + level + '">' + html + '</div>';

        $('sub_cat').insert(html);
    }
}
```

> Here is my form i m using onchange="this.form.submit()"

```
<form id="search_mini_form" action="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getResultUrl() ?>" method="get">
<select id="first_cat" name="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getQueryParamName() ?>" value="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getEscapedQueryText() ?>"   onchange="showCat(this,2);this.form.submit()">
<?php foreach ($tree['first'] as $cat): ?>
    <option   value="<?php echo $cat->getId() ?>"><?php echo $cat->getName() ?> </option>
<?php endforeach ?>
</select>
<button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Search') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Search') ?></span></span></button>
```

This code is adding field but it submit on first select i have a tree of select and i want to submit when its on last select

Comment: so, remove the `onchagne` attribute of the first `select` and add it to the last. I can't understand where the problem is.

Comment: Select is one inside select there are so many options if i set select on change submit it will submit 1st value hope u understand

Comment: Because the options are being generated dynamically. So we don't know where the last one is. But you can grab the elements siblings using the sibling method and see if it's the last element that way in an if statement.

https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: Add a validation on form submit and check if all the dropdowns have non-select value. If yes then proceed else dont submit the form.

Comment: Are you looking for the last `option` in the first `selrct` or the last `select` tag?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var strLastOptionSelected = $("select option:last-child").val();

$("select").change(function() {
  if ($(this).children("option:selected").val() === strLastOptionSelected) {
    alert("You have selected the last option");
    //Submit code
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```